# Get All items Group by a specific column values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, group-by, codeigniter-3

I have a table as below in MYSQL:

```
cname | vname | curl
---------------------
A     | 1     | url1
A     | 2     | url2
B     | 1     | url3
B     | 3     | url4
C     | 2     | url5
C     | 3     | url5
C     | 4     | url6
D     | 2     | url7
```

And I want to show the result as under:

```
1  |  2  |  3  |  4
-------------------
A  |  A  |  B  |  C
B  |  C  |  C  |
   |  D  |
```

In short, I am trying to show all the *cnames* group by *vnames*.

I have tried the following code in Codeigniter:

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('vname, cname, curl');
$this->db->from('tablename');
$this->db->order_by('cname');
$this->db->group_by('vname');
$res = $this->db->get();
if($res->num_rows()>0)
    var_dump($res->result());
```

I am getting only one row per *vname* as a result of `var_dump()`;

Plesae provide a solution for this problem.

Comment: Do not try to do this in sql, producing this output is very inefficient. Do the transformation in the php code

Comment: Also, to accommodate an arbitrary (unknown) number of `vname` value columns, you'd nee dynamic SQL, which is unwieldy.

Comment: @Shadow Bro I wrote above that I am doing it in Codeigniter (a PHP framework) and I have also shared the code.

Comment: Bro, your php code only generates an sql query and displays its result. You cannot do it that way.

Comment: @IT Sagar :Please this code:- $this->db->select('DISTINCT(vname), cname, curl');
$this->db->group_by('vname'); 
$query = $this->db->get('tablename');
$res = $this->db->get();
if($res->num_rows()>0)
    var_dump($res->result());

Comment: @Shadow But by your own (correct) admission, this is all the query that the problem requires

Comment: @Strawberry a group by query? I do not think so.

Comment: @Shadow - ok, it's *more* query than is required, but lose that line and the OP is good to go

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
$this->db->select('vname,GROUP_CONCAT(cname SEPARATOR ",") as cname');
$this->db->from('tablename');
$this->db->group_by('vname');
$res = $this->db->get();
```

Output :

```
+--------+--------+
| vname  | cname  |
+--------+--------+
| 1      | A,B    |
| 2      | A,C,D  |
| 3      | B,C    |
| 4      | C      |
+--------+--------+
```

Comment: This does not produce the expected output